# FPS count malfunction

Tags: java

I was adding a fps counter to my game and it worked fine before I attempted to add it, but now it's a white box and in the console it prints 0 fps at an alarming rate:

```
private void start() {
    if (running) {
        return;
    }
    running = true;

    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
    System.out.println("Error Free!");
}

public void stop() {
    if (!running) {
        return;
    }
    running = false;
    try {
        thread.join();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

public void run() {
    int frames = 0;
    double UnproccesedSeconds = 0;
    long PreviousTime = System.nanoTime();
    double SecondsPerTick = 1 / 60.0;
    int TickCount = 0;
    boolean Ticked = false;

    while (running) {
        long CurrentTime = System.nanoTime();
        long PassedTime = CurrentTime - PreviousTime;
        PreviousTime = CurrentTime;
        UnproccesedSeconds += PassedTime / 1000000000.0;

        while (UnproccesedSeconds < SecondsPerTick) {
            tick();
            UnproccesedSeconds -= SecondsPerTick;
            Ticked = true;
            TickCount++;
            if (TickCount % 60 == 0) {
                System.out.println(frames + "fps");
                PreviousTime += 1000;
                frames = 0;
            }
        }

        if (Ticked) {
            render();
            frames++;
        }
        render();
        frames++;
    }
}

private void tick() {
}

private void render() {
    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
    if (bs == null) {
        createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }
    Screen.render();

    for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH * LENGTH; i++) {
        PIXELS[i] = Screen.PIXELS[i];
    }

}
```

Ive looked it up and I cant find what's wrong; if someone could get back to me that would be amazing!

Comment: Here at SO you should avoid the word 'asap'... I removed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Thread's priority may be interfering with your games output pipeline.  That is, the counter is consuming so much of the runtime, that the engine pipeline can no longer keep up, which is probably why the FPS is been reported as 0.

You could try and lower the Thread's priority (when you create it) and/or place a Thread.yield some where in you calculation loop.  It does mean that the FPS calculation will be shunted to the back, but will allow the game engine to run properly (at at least faster then it was)

Comment: so pretty much your saying the fps counter is running faster then the game its self and isnt giving it enough time to load?

Comment: Not necessarily faster, but it might be competing with the rendering pipeline, not allowing enough to for the renderer to process it's through put in a timely manner...

Comment: so if i remove it, it will work agian. but for the sake of this project i eant to add it in eventually so how would i change the threat priorities?

Comment: "it worked fine before", so I would imagine removing it should get things running again.  To set the thread priority, simply call Thread.setPriority(int), where te lower the number, te lower the priority.

Comment: could you add it to the code for me? I'm having trouble with it

Comment: actually I got it to work without the yeild, I just removed it to its original state (before I added it) and I added the counter agian and it worked thanks! I was missing a {} in a statment.

Answer (score 0):

**If someone are lost here is what was wrong=)**

***This line***

```
while (UnproccesedSeconds < SecondsPerTick) {}
```

***Needs to be***

```
while (UnproccesedSeconds > SecondsPerTick) {}
```